# gtk configure error - No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found

Tags: c++, c, gtk, configure

I'm trying to install gtk+-3.6.4

My configuration breaks with the following error:

```
checking Pango flags... -pthread -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -L/usr/local/lib -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0  
checking for GDK_DEP... yes
checking for ATK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (atk atk-bridge-2.0) were not met:

No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ATK_CFLAGS
and ATK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

I've already installed

```
sudo apt-get install libatk1.0*
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Try to install libatk1.0-dev. That package contains header files for ATk

Comment: Try installing libatk-bridge2.0-dev

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same error, in my case i used

```
sudo apt-get install libatk-bridge2.0
```

Take note i'm using Ubuntu, anyways the package you want is `libatk-bridge2.0` if i'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `libatk1.0-dev`. That package contains header files for ATk. In Debian based systems, like Mint or Ubuntu, packages with different suffix have special meanings. Let's say libatk1.0 package. In Debian, it is splited to libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatk1.0-dev libatk1.0-dbg libatk1.0-doc.

If you just need ATK program(or other programs need it for package dependency), libatk1.0-0 is needed to install.

If we want to look up API documentation of ATK, libatk1.0-doc is needed, and we can look up its API manual in Devhelp.

libatk1.0-dbg package is almost never needed by common users. It's used for debugging ATK program.

libatk1.0-dev contains C header files. If a program is complied now, and it calls ATK's API, it needs atk's header files(like your problow). If you want to see where the headers files are installed, use this command: `dpkg -L libatk1.0-dev`.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libatk1.0* already does the installation -- mentioned in original post.

Comment: Use `pkg-config --cflags --libs atk` to check if header files of ATK have been already installed. On my laptop, the output is `-I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include  -latk-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0`. Alternatively, you can disable ATK in configure if atk program is useless.

Comment: I googled and figured out the difference between atk and atk-bridge. libatk-bridge2.0-dev package also needs to be installed.

Comment: I tried all the steps mentioned but I am still stuck with this error. Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the libatk-bridge package could not be installed through apt-get and it didn't find the related packages, so I downloaded and installed the packages from Ubuntu package repository:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libatk-bridge2.0-dev

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libs/libatk-bridge2.0-0